# Displaying locale percentage number with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization

Does anyone know how to display a percentage format based on the locale using the zend framework?  I've tried this below and it doesn't work for some reason:

```
$xx = Zend_Locale::getTranslation(null, 'PercentNumber'); // This outputs: "#,##0%" for locale 'en_us'
$percentage = Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber(133.3678, array('number_format' => $xx, 'locale' => $lang_LOCALE));
```

The output of $percentage is 133.3678.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no need in localizing a `%`. (Researched by checking out the Percentage article in Wikipedia)

Every country in the world uses the notation `x %` where x is 1 out of 100. The only difference is the number-representation: 1.00 in English for instance while 1,00 in Dutch. Arabic countries write right-to-left, thus `% x`.

I bet you can find out how to format numbers in Zend.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have done more research...just assumed it was different in other countries.  Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: This is ignorantly wrong. Percent sign have a different layout in different countries. Please [check Wikipedia first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign).

Comment: Having looked at wikipedia [Percent_sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign) and [Percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage), the _different layout_ seems *only* to be non-breaking space or no space.  Arabic has the percent on the right, using the symbol in @Jon's answer below

Comment: @earcam: Not true that the different layout is only non-breaking space or no space. In Turkish, for example, "the percent sign precedes rather than follows the number."

Answer (score 5):

That's somewhat true, in Arabic it is a different Unicode character: ٪ (U+066A), not the same as % (U+0025).

Comment: This should be the correct answer - the symbol itself is NOT always the same, hence why OS frameworks have a API to get this value per locale

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php